# How can we calculate the number of photons in the Universe, yet a state of defined photon number has zero electric field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

The expectation value of the electric field of a state with defined photon number is zero, so any electromagnetic wave (with non-zero expectation value) must be in a superposition state of definite photon number states.
Still, people talk all the time about the number of photons, like the number of photons in the Universe.

I guess this is some type of classical approximation, but aren't photon always quantum? Do we have to take the (semi)-classical limit in some particular way?

Now that I think of it, maybe the paradox can be explained accepting that the universe is not at a photon-number eigenstate, but what we are calculating is the expected value of number of photons.

Comment: I was just reading [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.55.3195), which might be relevant.

Comment: This is written as a question about cosmology, but I don't see anything about the logic that has anything to do with cosmology.

Comment: @Ben it's basically how does this question make sense:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276890/how-to-calculate-how-many-photons-are-in-the-universe/276900. I guess I'm asking, when does it make sense to talk about a definite number of photons, like those emmited from a lightbulb.

Comment: @jinawee: My point is that regardless of the context from which you came up with the question, it doesn't seem to me that the cosmology stuff is in any way relevant.