# power from Starlight vs background radiation

Tags: astrophysics

If our sun went dark (for the purpose of this question), which represents a larger (for very small values of larger) source of power, the stars (starlight) or background radiation?

Comment: Do you mean the cmb or radiation from other sources

Comment: Radiation from other sources of its substantial. I'm just curious how small the levels are and couldn't find a source anywhere for the power from the distant stars that hits us.

Comment: And also, do you mean from the stars in the sky you can see, say maximum a hemisphere. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I was looking all over for that. One source says **The total brightness [including airglow] of the sky on a clear, moonless night is about 2E-003 lux. Sirius, the brightest visible star, contributes about 1E-005 lux.** but it does not specify the complete sphere or a hemisphere.  I would guess most radiation from dust clouds etc is very cold, so my money is on the stars.

Comment: similar question [Number density of CMB photons?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196366/number-density-of-cmb-photons) with a very relevant answer