# How bright is the night sky in $\frac{\mathrm{W}}{\mathrm{m}^2}$?

Tags: visible-light, units, estimation, si-units

I'm looking at the Wikipedia page on [sky brightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_brightness), which gives the answer in "S10" units.

I've looked at the definition of S10 and I'm still completely at a loss as to how to convert that to SI units of irradiance, i.e. $\frac{\mathrm{W}}{\mathrm{m}^2}$.

Can someone show how to do the conversion?

Comment: I do not know about the conversion, but this paper has a table with some values: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~henrik/papers/nightsky/nightsky.pdf

Comment: The answer could only be given per unit solid angle or per square degree. Also, do you want a bolometric flux or just in some band?

Comment: Related: A plot of the brightness of the night sky as a function of frequency/wavelength can be found in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/196373/70207) about CMB photons.

Comment: @RobJeffries Hmm, I see what you mean.  I was thinking power per 1 m^2 area parallel to the ground, but that can be obtained from the per unit solid angle by integration.  Yes, bolometric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize after writing this answer that you're probably interested in the background as seen from Earth; this answer discusses the *cosmic* background, i.e. the background outside the Milky Way.

A recent review of the cosmic background radiation (CBR) across the full electromagnetic spectrum was compiled by [Hill et al. (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03694). The CBR is summed up in their Fig. 8:

[image: CBR]

Note that the $y$ axis shows $\nu I_\nu$, allowing for easier comparison of the total energy in a frequency band; peaks of similar width then have an energy ratio equal to the ratio of their heights. For instance, you can then see that the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) (CMB) dominates the CBR, with a total energy almost two orders of magnitude larger than the optical background (COB).

Dividing the spectrum by $\nu$ (to get the intensity *density*), and integrating over the full spectrum, I get a total intensity of the background of $1.0\times10^{-6}\,\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-2}\,\mathrm{sr}^{-1}$. The brightness from the full sky is then a factor $4\pi$ larger, i.e. $\sim 1.3\times10^{-5}\,\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-2}$.

Integrating only in the visible frequency band (from roughly $4.3\times10^{14}\,\mathrm{Hz}$ to $7.5\,\times10^{14}\,\mathrm{Hz}$), I get a smaller value of
$2.8\times10^{-9}\,\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-2}\,\mathrm{sr}^{-1}$, or
$3.6\times10^{-8}\,\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-2}$ for the full sky. Note though that the intensity in this region is rather uncertain, since COB observations are challenging due to the Milky Way's dust emission.